# Remove/hide Log a Call feed item from chatter page

Tags: chatter, tasks, chatter-feed-tracking

Customer is asking "When I log a call it can be seen by all on chatter. How do I stop this?"
I have checked the Global Actions and it seems **Create Feed Item** checkbox is checked.
What are the impacts of unchecking the checkbox

1. Is it feed item stop creating on chatter for all users?
2. If yes can we make this for specific users who are complaining about this?

Answer (score 0):

I have investigated this, and it appears the "Create Feed Item" check box indeed is the resolution for this issue. However, there is no way to narrow this down to specific users when it comes to turning this off. You can either turn it off for the whole organization, or not. Also, turning this off will make it so no feed items are created for Logging A Call at all.